# Pass XML file as input Arguments in Invoke-CimMethod using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, winrm, wsman

I am invoking a CIM method using power shell. Method arguments are in XML file like this

**XML input file:-**

```
<root>
<field1>value1</<field1>
<field2>value2</<field2>
</root>
```

**Powershell command:-**

```
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $inst -CimSession $session -MethodName method_name -Arguments @{field1='value1';field2='value2'}
```

When i am passing as command line argument like @{field1='value1';field2='value2'} it works fine.

Is there any way to directly pass it as xml input file in power shell like we have '-file:input.xml' in winrm?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the XML file directly to the command, but you could open the XML document and convert it to a PowerShell object first:

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content -Path YourFile.xml
```

I think you could then expand `Root` in to its own object via:

```
$Root = $XML | Select -ExpandProperty Root | Select Field1,Field2
```

I think then you could convert it to a hashtable via:

```
$RootHT = @{}
$Root.psobject.properties | Foreach { $RootHT[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

Then pass that hashtable to your command:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $inst -CimSession $session -MethodName method_name -Arguments $RootHT
```

You could combine some of the above steps to make this shorter if you wish.

Also FYI, your XML example was invalid (the closing element of field1 and 2 have a `</` in the wrong place which I expect was just a typo). It needs to be:

```
<root>
<field1>value1</field1>
<field2>value2</field2>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!.root element 'root' and child elements(field1, field2) may change for different xml file. I would like to have generic code that parses xml file and creates poweshell object. XML structure remains same(single level), but child elements will be field1, field2, field3 etc.